# can't start mysql server

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, 14.10, services

I can't start mysql server. Can anyone help?

```
root@note-remonts:/etc/mysql# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
Restarting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!

root@note-remonts:/etc/mysql# systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-09-26 18:51:16 -03; 8s ago
    Process: 8896 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, statu>

set 26 18:51:16 note-remonts systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
set 26 18:51:16 note-remonts systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart coun>
set 26 18:51:16 note-remonts systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
set 26 18:51:16 note-remonts systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
set 26 18:51:16 note-remonts systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
set 26 18:51:16 note-remonts systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: Let's start by actually stopping the process first - `sudo service mysql stop`.  This will stop the automatic reboot process.  Then, after a while (give it like 5-10 minutes), run exactly `sudo systemctl start mysql.service; sudo systemctl status -l mysql.service -n 50` exactly as is so we can get more scrollback data to try and ID what broke here.  Include the output from thsoe commands here, as well, because that way we can see the full scrollback of output during service start attempts.

Comment: Ok. I will do here.

Comment: You've tagged an EOL & thus off-topic release (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). Are you really using Ubuntu 14.10; it's years out of date and hasn't received security patches in years.